# How to change the font family in Next JS when used with Material UI?

Tags: material-ui, next.js

I am recently getting started with Next JS. for styling, I am using Material UI. one issue I am facing is with the fonts. I couldn't able to change the font family to a different font. as per the below example (Github link), I created a _document.js page inside my pages folder

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/nextjs/pages

**_document.js**
in the below code I tried changing **Roboto** with **Quicksand**

```
import React from "react";
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";
import { ServerStyleSheets } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
// import theme from "../components/Theme.js";

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head>
          {/* PWA primary color */}
          {/* <meta name="theme-color" content={theme.palette.primary.main} /> */}
          <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            // href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
          />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}
// `getInitialProps` belongs to `_document` (instead of `_app`),
// it's compatible with server-side generation (SSG).
MyDocument.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
 
  const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets();
  const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

  ctx.renderPage = () =>
    originalRenderPage({
      enhanceApp: (App) => (props) => sheets.collect(<App {...props} />),
    });

  const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);

  return {
    ...initialProps,
    // Styles fragment is rendered after the app and page rendering finish.
    styles: [
      ...React.Children.toArray(initialProps.styles),
      sheets.getStyleElement(),
    ],
  };
};
```

Also, I customized my MUI theme object as below

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "dark",
    background: {
      default: "#212121",
    },
    typography: {
      fontFamily: "Quicksand",
    },
  },
});
```

**Layout.js**

```
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/styles";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import Divider from "@material-ui/core/Divider";
import NavBar from "./NavBar.js";
import Footer from "./Footer.js";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    minHeight: "100vh",
  },
  main: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(0),
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(10),
  },
}));

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "dark",
    background: {
      default: "#212121",
    },
    typography: {
      fontFamily: "Quicksand",
    },
  },
});

function Layout({ children }) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />

        <Container component="main" className={classes.main} maxWidth="md">
          <NavBar />
          <Divider />
          {children}
          <Divider />
          <Footer />
        </Container>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Layout;
```

But no luck. can anyone please advise?

Thanks In Advance
Venk

Comment: You have to implement the theme somewhere. I usually use it as a HOC (higher-order component). In _app.js, you'd use `ThemeProvider` - There are other ways, but I find this way to be the easiest. I'll post it below so you can review it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what worked for me with Google Fonts, MUI v5, NextJs v13 (TS)

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/font
https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/typography/#adding-amp-disabling-variants

Add primary and secondary variant to theme

```
import { Barlow, Cormorant } from "@next/font/google";

export const barlow = Barlow({
  weight: ["200", "400", "500", "600", "700"],
  display: "swap",
  fallback: ["Helvetica", "Arial", "sans-serif"],
});

export const cormorant = Cormorant({
  weight: ["300", "400", "500", "600", "700"],
  display: "swap",
  fallback: ["Times New Roman", "Times", "serif"],
});

declare module "@mui/material/styles" {  
  interface TypographyVariants {
    primary: React.CSSProperties;
    secondary: React.CSSProperties;
  }
  interface TypographyVariantsOptions {
    primary?: React.CSSProperties;
    secondary?: React.CSSProperties;
  }
}

declare module "@mui/material/Typography" {
  interface TypographyPropsVariantOverrides {
    primary: true;
    secondary: true;
  }
}

let theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: barlow.style.fontFamily,
    body1: {
      fontFamily: barlow.style.fontFamily,
    },
    primary: {
      fontFamily: barlow.style.fontFamily,
    },
    secondary: {
      fontFamily: cormorant.style.fontFamily,
    },
  },
});
```

in component as sx prop

```
    <Typography
      sx={{
        fontFamily: theme.typography.secondary.fontFamily,
      }}
    >
      More About Us:
    </Typography>
```

cormorant overides the default

[image]

or props

```
        <Typography
          variant="secondary"
        >
          More About Us:
        </Typography>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your  in `_app.js` with a ThemeProvider.

Example _app.js:

```
import '../styles/globals.scss'
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import Header from '../components/Header'
import { AuthProvider } from '../contexts/AuthContext'
import { CartProvider } from '../contexts/CartContext'
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core'
import theme from '../styles/theme'


export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const router = useRouter()

  return(
    <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
      <CartProvider>
        <AuthProvider>
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Header />
            <motion.div key={router.pathname} className="main">
              <Component { ...pageProps } />
            </motion.div>
          </ThemeProvider>
        </AuthProvider>
      </CartProvider>
    </AnimatePresence>
  )
}
```

Example theme file:

```
import { createTheme, responsiveFontSizes } from "@material-ui/core"

let theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#0277bd',
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#b2ff59',
    },
    darkGray: {
      main: '#333333'
    },
  },
})

theme = responsiveFontSizes(theme)
export default theme
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the details. actually, I already wrapped the content (_app.js) with the Theme Provider. I actually created a components folder with a Layout.js page in it. I imported the entire _app.js content as a child into the Layout.js page and wrapped the Theme Provider for it.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that. Hmmm. I'll delete/amend my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

In **Nextjs V10+** with **material-ui**

**_document.js**

Don't forget to add this link tag before your fonts for improving the performance

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
```

**_app.js**

add the override object to make your font a global font in your app instead of **Roboto** the default

```
const theme = responsiveFontSizes(
  createMuiTheme({
    // your custom UI Config ,
    typography: {
      fontFamily: "Quicksand",
    },
    overrides: {
      MuiCssBaseline: {
        "@global": {
          "@font-face": [
            {
              fontFamily: "Quicksand",
              fontStyle: "normal",
              fontDisplay: "swap",
              fontWeight: // your font weight,
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    },
  })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I finally got this figured out! I was being pretty silly.

The BIG thing to know is that you can't just use the font name in your theme, you need to use the dynamic `ubuntu.style.fontFamily` where `ubuntu` is your font **variable**.

I set the font globally in my app with just one file

#### _app.js

```
import { Ubuntu } from "next/font/google";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";

const ubuntu = Ubuntu({
  subsets: ["latin"],
  weight: ["300", "400", "700"],
  style: ["normal", "italic"],
});

const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: `${ubuntu.style.fontFamily}, Arial`,
  },
  overrides: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      "@global": {
        "@font-face": [
          {
            fontFamily: `Ubuntu, ${ubuntu.style.fontFamily}`,
            fontStyle: "normal",
            fontDisplay: "swap",
            fontWeight: "400", // your font weight,
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  },
});

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <style jsx global>{`
        html {
          font-family: ${ubuntu.style.fontFamily};
        }
      `}</style>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how you understand the Mui theme concept. Let's just talk about NextJs first.

NextJs is no different from React. To set the global font-family you just have to put `font-family: your desired font` into the `html, body {}` block inside the global.css which is already imported at the top level of `_app.js`. Every component will use that global font unless it has custom styles. Example:

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Quicksand, cursive;
}
```

Now, with Mui, components use a designed style system which conclude default font option as well. To inject your custom style into every single Mui's component you need to wrap all of them inside a top/root level `<ThemeProvider theme={yourCutomTheme}>` component to override the defaults, reference: [Custom Theming from Mui official doc](https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/).

Things are not that complicated tho.

Comment: Hi Raymond, Thanks for the details. I actually used ThemeProvider as well, Sorry I didn't include that part in my initial post. can you please check my initial post once, I just included the Layout.js code as well with ThemeProvider wrapping my {children} (imported _app.js as children into my Layout.js file).

Comment: Because you're doing it wrong, the `typography` property should not be child of palette. Try moving it out of the `palette` closure and see the magic

Comment: Thanks. In fact, It worked like a magic. Thanks for your time and helping out